# Opening Runspace Pool using custom classes (C#) throws error

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell, runspace

I have to add multithreading capabilities to a PowerShell script. Unfortunately I get an error when I try to open an runspace pool using custom C# classes in the `InitialSessionState` object. The following example is a DEMO code only, not the original script. You can copy&paste it and it will run without any modifications needed. What is really strange is, that all seems to work correctly despite the error message coming up when opening the runspace pool.

This is the error message (translated):

> Error while loading the extended type data file: Error in type data "FooBar.BarClass": The TypeData must have: "Members", "TypeConverters", "TypeAdapters" or "StandardMembers".

I have already worked and tested for hours and have no idea what is the reason for that message. And yes, I know that there are very good libraries and cmdlets available for multithreading, but I cannot use them for different reasons.

```
# Simple c-sharp classes
Add-Type -TypeDef @"
namespace FooBar {
    public class FooClass {
        public string Foo() {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }

    public class BarClass {
        public string Bar() {
            return "Bar";
        }
    }
}
"@

function callFooBar {
    [FooBar.FooClass]$foo = New-Object FooBar.FooClass
    [FooBar.BarClass]$bar = New-Object FooBar.BarClass

    $foo.Foo() + $bar.Bar()
}

$scriptBlock = {
    Write-Output ( callFooBar )
}

# Setting up an initial session state object
$initialSessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()

# Getting the function definition for the functions to add
$functionDefinition = Get-Content function:\callFooBar
$functionEntry = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateFunctionEntry -ArgumentList 'callFooBar', $functionDefinition

# And add it to the iss object
[void]$initialSessionState.Commands.Add($functionEntry)

# Get the type data for the custom types to add
$typeData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.TypeData -ArgumentList 'FooBar.FooClass'
$typeEntry = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateTypeEntry -ArgumentList $typeData, $false

# And add it to the iss object
[void]$initialSessionState.Types.Add($typeEntry)

# Get the type data for the custom types to add
$typeData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.TypeData -ArgumentList 'FooBar.BarClass'
$typeEntry = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateTypeEntry -ArgumentList $typeData, $false

# And add it to the iss object
[void]$initialSessionState.Types.Add($typeEntry)

# Create Runspace pool
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, ([int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS + 1), $initialSessionState, $Host)
$RunspacePool.ApartmentState = 'MTA'
[void]$RunspacePool.Open()  # <<<< Error occurs here!

[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$Jobs = @()

1..2 | % {
    $job = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create($initialSessionState)
    $job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [void]$job.AddScript($scriptBlock)   
    $jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        RunNum = $_
        Pipe   = $job
        Result = $job.BeginInvoke()
    }
}

do {
} while ($jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"

$Results = @()
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
    $Results += $job.Pipe.EndInvoke($job.Result)
}

$Results

$RunspacePool.Close()
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

Comment: The error message suggests that you're using your custom types as if they were ETS TypeData definitions, which they're not.

Answer (score 2):

@mklement0 Your hint leads me to the right direction! Custom C# classes with type-definition must be added in a different way to the runspacepool. This was working now (after a few hours testing with all possible runspace methods...):

```
# Get the script data for the custom c# class to add
$scriptDefinition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.ScriptConfigurationEntry -ArgumentList 'FooBar.FooClass', $false
$scriptEntry = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateScriptEntry -ArgumentList $scriptDefinition

# And add it to the iss object
[void]$initialSessionState.Commands.Add($scriptEntry)

# Get the script data for the custom c# class to add
$scriptDefinition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.ScriptConfigurationEntry -ArgumentList 'FooBar.BarClass', $false
$scriptEntry = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateScriptEntry -ArgumentList $scriptDefinition

# And add it to the iss object
[void]$initialSessionState.Commands.Add($scriptEntry)
```

Not by type, but with script and command. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but looking at the PowerShell API types you're instantiating, it's not clear to me that their purpose is to add custom _types_. Your code actually runs if you simply _omit_ trying to add the custom types explicitly - tough I'm not sure why.